# So i need to submit this code to my teacher. He has a hidden list for my function to work off. Its not working though

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have no idea what im doing wrong. I know my teacher has a hidden list that it runs...So i need to submit this code to my teacher. He has a hidden list for my function to work off. Its not working though.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>First and Last</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
            Input:
            Processing:
            Output:
        */
            function addEnds(list)
            {
                /*var list=[1,2,3,4,5];*/

                var first=list[0]

                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    var last=list[i];
                }

                var math=first+last;

                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=math;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        Click for both ends:<button type="button" onclick="addEnds()">
            Click Here
        </button>
        <div id="output">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define **Its not working**. What is the expected result and what is the current result?

Comment: it just comes up with this when i enter it in: addEnds function failed. TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: What is the question of the problem you're given by your teacher?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the goal here is to add the first and last item from a given list and display it on the page. But it's not really clear on how the list is given to the function. I assumed the following and made a solution based on what I understood from his question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the goal of this code is to add the first and last item in an array and displaying it on the page, this is what the code would have to do?

HTML

---

```
Click for both ends:
<button type="button" id="btnList">Click Here</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS

---

```
document.getElementById("btnList").addEventListener("click", addEnds, false);

function addEnds() {
    var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    var first = list[0];
    var last = list[list.length-1];

    var math = first + last;

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = math;
}
```

ofcourse, I have no idea what your teacher intends to do with a "hidden" list.
So if you could elaborate a bit more on that part, we might be able to help you out with that as well.

But for now, I fixed your code by adding an event listener to your button in the onload-function. This will trigger your function which will then add both the first and last item from the list and display it.

to see it in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/kgs2orvx/)

**EDIT**

---

I was playing around a bit with your code in jQuery and I ended up making this.
Maybe you can find some inspiration. Doesn't your teacher use jQuery, because it makes life a lot easier. Except if you're just learning, than it's good to know the basics from Javascript.

[Another version](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/kgs2orvx/1/)